# CSS - I can't get my menu to center(horizontally) dynamically

Tags: html, css

I have a simple layout like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
           </ul>
      </div>
  </body>
```

But I can't figure out how to center this menu horizontally and dynamically. The CSS is in here http://codepen.io/syarifphmy/pen/egvsk. I'm thinking it has something to do with the width of the < ul >. But if I state it in a fixed size say for example 500px, then it won't be dynamic. I want it to fit according to the lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `text-align` to center (non-floated) inline-block children:

```css
ul{
  text-align: center;
}
li{
  display: inline-block;
  float: none; /* default value */
}
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
}

li:first-child{
  border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
}
li:last-child{
  border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
}
ul{
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding:0;
}
a{
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:5vmin;
}
li{
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: #98bf21;
  padding:5px 20px;
}
li:hover{
  background-color: #7A991A;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna use this one. I have a new code now and I have trouble with a little gap under my links that I can't seem to get rid of. So how do I get rid of it? http://codepen.io/syarifphmy/pen/svJLx

Comment: You can set the height of your header to match the height of your links. "height:63px;" worked for me.

Comment: @user4215649 That's because inline-block elements have `vertical-align: baseline` by default. You can use, for example, `vertical-align: middle` to fix that. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ktFLI

Answer (score 1):

Use display: table;

```
ul{
  display: table;
  list-style: none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpxyD

Also, unrelated: I would recommend giving your anchors display: block, so they use the entire li space. Right now you have to find the text inside the li to actually click the link.

Comment: thanks for the tip, will definitely use that. Sorry for the late response, had trouble with internet, I have a new code and I can't seem to get rid of this little gap under my links and I can't figure out the problem http://codepen.io/syarifphmy/pen/svJLx

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the codepen snippit here, so i made my own fiddle.   Not sure if you wanted horiz or vertical items, so i made both.

```
div#one { width: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
div#one ul { list-style: none; position: relative; float: left; display: block; left: 50%; }
div#one ul li { position: relative; float: left; display: block; right: 50%; margin-right: 20px; }


div#two { width: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
div#two ul { list-style: none; position: relative; float: left; display: block; left: 50%; }
div#two ul li { position: relative; display: block; right: 50%; text-align: center; }
```

This fires on the markup:

```
<div id="one">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
       </ul>
  </div>

<div id="two">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">A REALLY LONG TITLE</a></li>
       </ul>
  </div>
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x40h8Ldh/1/

Be sure you are using a STRICT DTD as some of these concepts will not work cross-browser with just `<html>` declared.